# Bandwidth transmission for uniform PCM using m-ary PPM

Tags: digital-communications, bandwidth

I have a uniform PCM whose bandwidth is W = 1Hz and n = 12 bits, i.e. the transmission bandwidth B_T = n*W = 12Hz.

Given this features of the signal, I need to calculate the minimum transmission badnwidth B_T if the same PCM signal is transmitted using m-ary PPM with M=4 and M=8.

I don't yet understand how the choice of transmitting with Pulse Position Modulation will change the bandwidth. I intuitively guess that it will increase with respect to the initial B_T = 12Hz but I can't tell how to calculate that.

Comment: That "transmission bandwidth" statement (first sentence) seems wrong. The whole sentence is semantically questionable. I think what you call "bandwidth" is a bit rate, and it seems you're confusing that with the physical way it's encoded.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The transmission bandwidth is actually supposed to be bit rate as described in this question. And you're right. This whole question needs to be rewritten and asked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the notions of bandwidth and will look only at the time domain, where, if I understand the question correctly, $12$ bits need to be transmitted in one second using $4$-ary PPM (alternatively $8$-ary PPM).

**$4$-ary PPM signaling:** The $12$ data bits get partitioned into $6$ dibits taking on one of $4$ values $00, 01, 10, 11$. We divide each one-second epoch into *six* $1000/6\approx 166.666\cdots$ millisecond *frames* for the $6$ dibits, and each frame into *four* $41.666\cdots$-millisecond time slots for the $4$ possible locations of the single pulse that will be transmitted in each frame. Thus, a total of $6$ pulses, each of duration $41.666\cdots$ milliseconds will be transmitted in one second, with the location of each pulse conveying $2$  bits of information over the channel.

**$8$-ary PPM signaling:** The $12$ data bits get partitioned into $4$ octets, the one-second epoch into $4$ $250$-millisecond frames, with each frame being divided into $8$ $31.25$-millisecond slots. There would be a total of $4$ pulses of duration $31.25$ milliseconds being transmitted in each one-second epoch, with the pulse locations conveying $3$ bits of information over the channel.

I will leave it to the OP to decide what the transmission bandwidth is from this description.